# How to store Huffman Codes in a binary file c++?

Tags: c++, huffman-code

I was working on a Huffman project to compress text files. I was able to generate the required codes. I read the whole file and accordingly stored the codes in a "vector char" variable. I also padded the encoded vector.

```
vector<char> padding(vector<char> text)
{

    int num = text.size();
    unsigned int pad_value = 32-(num%32);

    for(int i=0;i<pad_value;i++){
        text.push_back('0');
    }


    string pad_info = bitset<32>(pad_value).to_string();

    for(int i=pad_info.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
        text.insert(text.begin(),pad_info[i]);
    }

    return text;

}
```

I padded on the base of 32 bits, as I was thinking if using an array of "unsigned int" to directly store the integers in a binary file so that they occupy 4 bytes for every 32 characters. I used this function for that:

```
vector<unsigned int> build_byte_array(vector<char> padded_text)
{
    vector<unsigned int> byte_arr;

    for(int i=0;i<padded_text.size();i+=32)
    {
        string byte="";
        for(int j=i;j<i+32;j++){
            byte += padded_text[j];
        }
        unsigned int b = stoul(byte,nullptr,2);
        //cout<<b<<":"<<byte<<endl;

        byte_arr.push_back(b);
    }

    return byte_arr;
}
```

Now the problem is when I write this byte array to binary file using

```
    ofstream output("compressed.bin",ios::binary);
    for(int i=0;i<byte_array.size();i++){
        unsigned int a = byte_array[i];
        output.write((char*)(&a),sizeof(a));
    }
```

I get a binary file which is bigger than the original text file. How do I solve that or what error am I making.

Edit : I tried to compress a file of about 2,493 KB (for testing purposes) and it generated a compressed.bin file of 3,431 KB. So, I don't think padding is the issue here.
I also tried with 15KB file but the size of always increases after using this algo.

I tried using:

```
for(int i=0;i<byte_array.size();i++){
        unsigned int a = byte_array[i];
        char b = (char)a;
        output.write((char*)(&a),sizeof(b));
    }
```

but after using this I am unable to recover the original byte array when decompressing the file.

Comment: Your method of writing the byte array makes no sense whatsoever. Just do `output.write(byte_array.data(), byte_array.size());`. No loop.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That would not work, since the OP's "byte_array" is actually an array of four-byte integers. (The OP has misused the term "byte.) Your code would not compile, since `write()` is expecting a `char *`, and if you cast the pointer, you would only write about one-fourth of the data. It would need to be `output.write((char const *)byte_array.data(), byte_array.size() * sizeof(unsigned int));`

Comment: How much bigger? How much input are you trying to compress? You are padding the front with 32 bits and the back with 1..32 bits. For small input, your compression might not be compressing much, or might be expanding a little, and then you are adding a bunch of bits on top of that.

Comment: @MarkAdler You are right, I confused it with some other array which is `vector<char>`.

Comment: Note that you may not want to store the data exactly like this: If implemented this way your data cannot be transferred between systems using a different endianness. better work with a array/vector of `uint8_t` in the first place...

Comment: @fabian I'm guessing that this is for a homework assignment, so portability is likely not a concern. However there are other reasons as well to use bytes, as recommended in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int a = byte_array[i];
output.write((char*)(&a),sizeof(a));
```

The size of the write is `sizeof(a)` which is usually 4 bytes.
An `unsigned int` is not a byte. A more suitable type for a byte would be `std::byte`, `uint8_t`, or `unsigned char`.

Comment: I tried that but recovering the byte array back from the binary file to decompress does not work that way.

Comment: His code is correct, writing four bytes at a time. He has simply misused the term "byte".

Comment: @Gaurav There is no reason that you can't do this with bytes instead of ints, and you should, in order to reduce the padding.

Comment: @MarkAdler how do I write those "bits" to file, that is the main problem. If I use simple char it just interpret each "bit" as a "byte", hence increasing the size. That's why I thought of using "int" as they are stored in 32 bit format but it doesn't appear to do so unless I'm making a mistake.

Comment: You put eight bits in each byte, just like you are now putting 32 bits in each int.

Answer (score 0):

You are expanding your data with padding, so if you're not getting much compression or there's not much data to begin with, the output could easily be larger.

You don't need to pad nearly as much as you do. First off, you are adding 32 bits when the data already ends on a word boundary (when `num` is a multiple of 32). Pad *zero* bits in that case. Second, you are inserting 32 bits at the start to record how many bits you padded, where five bits would suffice to encode 0..31. Third, you could write bytes instead of `int`s, so the padding on the end could be 0..7 bits, and you could prepend three bits instead of five. The padding overall could be reduced from your current 33..64 bits to 3..10 bits.